# Assembly language math co-processor

Tags: assembly, geometry

I am at the starting point to learn assembly language programming at the university and I have a mini-project to do: to calculate the area of a triangle, having the sides as input from the keyboard. The most of the project is done, however I need to do the calculations using the math co-processor and I don't get any result from what I wrote. This is my first try with the math co-processor, maybe I'm noob, but I don't see anything happening inside.

Here's the code:

```
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
SIDEONE DQ 3
SIDETWO DQ 4
SIDETHREE DQ 5
HALFPERIMETER DQ ?
RESULT DQ ?
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA

COMPUTATION PROC FAR
PUSH DS
XOR AX,AX
PUSH AX
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX

FINIT
FILD SIDEONE
FILD SIDETWO
FILD SIDETHREE
FADD ST3,ST0
FADD ST2,ST0
FADD ST1,ST0
FSTP HALFPERIMETER
FWAIT

FINIT
FILD HALFPERIMETER
FILD SIDEONE
FILD SIDETWO
FILD SIDETHREE
FSUB ST3,ST0
FILD HALFPERIMETER
FSUB ST2,ST0
FILD HALFPERIMETER
FSUB ST1,ST0
FILD HALFPERIMETER
FMULP ST3,ST0
FMULP ST2,ST0
FMULP ST1,ST0
FSQRT
FSTP RESULT
FWAIT

RET
COMPUTATION ENDP
CODE ENDS
END COMPUTATION
```

It is just a testing unit, if this one works I will connect the procedure with the rest of my program, but first I want to see this one working.

Comment: Have you traced through the computation in a debugger? Also, any particular reason you're not using SSE?

Comment: I traced it, but while the math co-processor does his work the debugger isn't showing anything, just the instruction pointer is incremented after every instruction. I'm not using SSE, because our professor wants things to be done this way, unfortunately.

Comment: I never really bothered with the x87 but think I can spot a couple of issues off-hand. For one thing you're mixing up 64-bit integers and 64-bit floats in the loads/stores. Either define the data with DQ and use FILD/FISTP or define them with REAL8 and use FLD/FST. Secondly you seem to want FADDP in the beginning. Thirdly you're not restoring your data segment leading to a nasty crash on return. Oh, and do try to balance the stack instead of using FINIT. Lastly FWAIT hasn't been required for the last 25 years or so

Comment: Thanks you, but I don't understand a part of it: what do you mean by restoring my data segment?

Comment: Meanwhile I succeeded, thanks for your help. The main problems were with FISTP, FADDP and two indexes were mistaken in the algorithm.

Comment: I'm not certain how this is invoked but you're pushing the previous data segment (DS register) onto the stack, seemingly so it may be replaced by an alternate segment with your variables. Normally you would then restore the original at the end of the function through a POP. Instead you're also pushing 0 and issuing a far return, causing the processor to jump to offset 0 within the original segment instead of returning to the original caller. This may be intentional but it looks exceedingly suspicious to me

Comment: I will change this data segment cand invoke this procedure from another file. This was just for testing that this module works. Thanks for your help again.